# Upload de arquivo com laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

Estou seguindo a documentação para realizar o upload de arquivos para a pasta `storage` porém o caminho que a função retorna não é o mesmo caminho em que o arquivo foi armazenado, [veja na a documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#storing-uploaded-files):

`$path = $request->photo->store('images');`

O caminho retornado para `$path` é `/home/usuario/pasta/projeto/images` e o arquivo é armazenado em `/home/usuario/pasta/projeto/app/storage/app/images`. Este último trecho "`/app/storage/`" foi definido pelo arquivo `filesystem.php` dentro da pasta `config`:

```
'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
    ...

],
```

Como posso fazer para pegar o caminho real do arquivo salvo?